# Widget/Image Warping And Distortion in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rendering

Widgets like the Transform widget make it easy to scale, translate, and skew widgets in Flutter. But there is no apparent way to **warp** or distort an image out of the box.

Take this example of warping for instance:

[image: Example 1]

Assume this widget is a Container with a Decoration Image and a Text widget as its child. Here, the widget is not clipped by a bezier curve or path. The widget is 'stretched', or warped. This may not be possible to achieve using the Container widget, but could it be done with a CustomPainter?

Also, take a look at this example:

[image: Example 2]

Here the image is distorted using a ripple effect. Is it even possible to replicate that using Flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to go about this is to convert the widget to an image and transform it, either by editing the pixel data or by painting a 3d texture.

1. [Example using Image manipulation](https://gist.github.com/wilsonowilson/6d0b56cab01fb5f00e110eb3b413dd79)
2. [Example using custom paint](https://gist.github.com/slightfoot/2a624dd982500cc78a364d252bb0c1e6)

The latter is more performant, but the first will give you more control over how the image is distorted.

1. [See {1} in action](https://twitter.com/WilsonSquared/status/1372266725924868100?s=20)
2. [See {2} in action](https://twitter.com/devangelslondon/status/1372354436547362823?s=20)